# I want to do subqueries of sparksql with dataframe operations

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to operate on a data frame from the following query.
I'm not sure how to implement that, so please let me know.

**example table**

```
| date                    | name            |
| ----------------------- | --------------- |
| 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z    | row1            |
| 2021-01-02T00:00:00Z    | row1            |
| 2021-01-03T00:00:00Z    | row1            |
| 2021-01-03T00:00:00Z    | row1            |
| 2021-01-04T00:00:00Z    | row1            |
| 2021-01-11T00:00:00Z    | row2            |
| 2021-01-12T00:00:00Z    | row2            |
```

```
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) as number FROM test_tables) AS test1 WHERE number <= 3')
```

**Execution result**

| date | name | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-03T00:00:00Z | row1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03T00:00:00Z | row1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-04T00:00:00Z | row1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-11T00:00:00Z | row2 | 1 |
| 2021-01-12T00:00:00Z | row2 | 2 |

How to do this in a data frame?

**Example of a data frame**

```
df.withColumn("name",f.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(f.col("date").desc()))
```

Comment: The case is a little different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the combination of `withColumn` and `filter`

```
window = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(f.col("date").desc())

df.withColumn("number", f.row_number().over(window)) \
    .filter(f.col("number") <= 3) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+--------------------+----+------+
|date                |name|number|
+--------------------+----+------+
|2021-01-12T00:00:00Z|row2|1     |
|2021-01-11T00:00:00Z|row2|2     |
|2021-01-04T00:00:00Z|row1|1     |
|2021-01-03T00:00:00Z|row1|2     |
|2021-01-03T00:00:00Z|row1|3     |
+--------------------+----+------+
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try this.

window should be WindowSpec

Comment: @jp_spark did you import `Window`  from pyspark.sql.window import Window